# Clicking Links to Change Displayed Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[General Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCfbc.jpg)

I'm working on a tool for work to help streamline some things, but I've never been good at best practices and wanted to make sure I did this right.

I want the site to load with only column A visible. Click a link in column A, column B is generated with proper links. Click a link in column B, column C is generated. Click a different link in column A, column B is replaced with the new proper links (and if column C was already visible, get rid of it completely).

My current idea is having a clever div structure so I can add or remove a "hidden" class using jQuery on all children. Each column is a floated div with styled links. I'm not sure if the cleanest way to do this would just be having a parent for each potential section, then labeling each possibility with a class for a selector. That way I could use the jQuery children().addClass("Hidden") on the parent container for each section that I've defined to come after the one the link was clicked in.

I'm not sure I have access at work to a MySQL database, and I can't put company information on my personal sandbox website, so I think I'm stuck with javascript for the most part. Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

The code below is incomplete, just wanted to give an idea of what I was already thinking. i.e.

```
//This would be part of function modemBrands when Arris is passed, currently using if else statements for each option.

$('.ModemMods').children().addClass("Hidden");
$(".Arris").removeClass("Hidden");
```

~

```
<div class="NavCon">
    <nav>
     <!-- Brand options -->
        <div class="LinkCon">
            <a href="#" onclick="modemBrands('Arris')">Arris</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="modemBrands('Motorola')">Motorola</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="modemBrands('SMC')">SMC</a>
            <a href="#" onclick="modemBrands('Ubee')">Ubee</a>
        </div>

        <div class="ModemMods">
            <div class="LinkCon Arris">
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG860A')">DG860A</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG1670')">DG1670</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG860A')">DG860A</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG1670')">DG1670</a>
            </div>

            <div class="LinkCon Motorola Hidden">
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG860A')">DG860A</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG1670')">DG1670</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG860A')">DG860A</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG1670')">DG1670</a>
            </div>

            <div class="LinkCon SMC Hidden">
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG860A')">DG860A</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG1670')">DG1670</a>
            </div>

            <div class="LinkCon Ubee Hidden">
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG860A')">DG860A</a>
                <a href="#" onclick="modemMods('DG1670')">DG1670</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="ModemRegion">
        </div>

    </nav>
</div>
```

Am I on the right track? Should I just have the function tied to links in column A add the Hidden class to all of the parent containers for columns B or C each time I click it? Or is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not use onclick. Use `addEventListener` (vanilla JS) or `.click()` (jQuery).

   Why? Separation of concerns. Your HTML is for content and layout. Your CSS is for styling. Your JS is for scripting.
2. MySQL is not a programming language. It is a database system. You can either hard code in the values, store it in a JSON file somewhere, or use a database and a server side scripting language to load it from the DB.
3. Try separating data from your layout. For example:

.

```
var motorola = {name: "Motorola", modems: ["ABC123", "BCD123", "XYZ123"]};
var cisco = {name: "Cisco", modems: ["MEOW123", "LOL123", "STACKOVERFLOW"]};
var vendors = [motorola, cisco];

for (var i in vendors) {
    $link = $("<a>").text(vendors[i].name);
    $link.attr("data-name", i);
    $link.click(vendorClickHandler);
}

function vendorClickHandler(e) {
    var vendorName = $(this).attr("data-name");
    var vendor = vendors.filter(function(t) { return t.name === vendorName })[0]; // basically, search vendors for an elem with this name

    for (var i in vendor.modems) {
         // ...
    }
}
```

This would be a good jQuery-level architecture. The "best" architecture? A templating library (but that's not necessary at this level).

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot tonight! Any links off the top of your head that may prove useful if I want to read up on building a templating library? I'm mostly a hobbyist and have never had to think of scope or look into more than solving one problem at a time with what I've done, so I'm sure it'd be useful to read up on that.

Comment: After doing a bit of reading, it looks like a JSON file is probably going to be my best bet. I also haven't used it at all yet, and it seems like a tool I should have been using for a long time.